# .NET Listbox: in ItemChecked event know if item was clicked

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, listbox

I have a ListBox in my winforms app and I need to handle the ItemChecked becaue each time the users cliks an item i need to some stuff. The problem is that I also need to change the Checked property in some other events of the form. In those cases I need to avoid do that stuff.

Example:

```
private void listBox1_ItemChecked(object sender, ItemCheckedEventArgs e)
{
  if (true) //Should check if item was clicked.
  {
     //Do some stuff
  }
  else //If the event was fired because I changed the Checked property from the code
  {
     //Do some other stuff
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use a bool variable let's say ManualRaise. When you are raising the event through code, set ManualRaise = true and inside your event you can check '

```
if(ManualRaise) 
{
// this was manual event raise
ManualRaise = False
} 
else 
{
}
```

and in that event where you will raise the list box event, set the ManualRaise to true.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, I think you want to unsubscribe to the ItemCheck event when you are changing the Checked property behind the scenes (i.e. the user didnt cause the Checked property to change).

So for example:

```
public void SetupListBoxEnables()
{  
   // Do not listen for Checked change events
   listBox1.ItemCheck -= listBox1_ItemChecked;
   // Change a bunch of Checked properties
   // ....

   // Listen again for Checked change events
   listBox1.ItemCheck += listBox1_ItemChecked;
}
```

Comment: @antisanity and @SwDevMan81 Maybe I've been doing silverlight and WPF too long but that just looks hackish.  I've done some my share of winforms development as well and always find a way around the problem without having to wire and unwire events.  Too many dependencies going on for my taste.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It does work but in first place its more code than having the flag as @haris said. On the other hand (and mainly) this solution makes I have to put the code of `//Do some other stuff` in every place I change the Checked property.

Answer (score 0):

I keep a Boolean value in the class to keep track of when actions are performed by the user or automatically by the system.  Whenever I am about to change, for example, CheckBox.Checked, I set the Boolean to True, then back to False after I'm done.

In the Checked event handler, I check to see if the event occurred while the Boolean is true to determine which code to execute.

```
private Boolean blnSystem = false;

private void SystemChanges()
{
    try
    {
        blnSystem = true;

        //Code which changes listBox1 Item Checked values
    }
    catch
    {
        //Error handler
    }
    finally
    {
        blnSystem = false;
    }
}

private void listBox1_ItemChecked(object sender, ItemCheckedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!blnSystem) //Should check if item was clicked.
    {
        //Do some stuff
    }
    else //If the event was fired because I changed the Checked property from the code
    {
        //Do some other stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the answers you have gotten so far are great.  I'm wondering, however, if it might make more sense to put the logic that is specific to programmatic setting the selected list item in the same code that actually sets the checked property rather than rely on the ItemChecked event.  The event can call the same code that the previous code does.

example:

```
public void SomeFunction()
{
  // set checkbox
  listBox1.Items[index].Checked = true;

  // Handle the change in state
  HandleState();
}

protected void listBox1_ItemChecked(object sender, ItemCheckedEventArgs e) 
{
  HandleState();
}

   private function HandleState()
   {
      // Handle your visual state here
   }
```

Comment: I realy coudn't understand your solution. Could you help me to get it. Also have in mind that to fire ItemChecked you need to change Checked property, not Selected.

Comment: @Diego Sorry, I was thinking of two things at once.  Indeed, it's the checked property you are looking for, not the selected property.  The first line of code in the example function is incorrect.  As for understanding the solution, basically you want what is called inversion of control.  Instead of having the ItemChecked event control the UI you are "inverting" and moving the control of the UI to a more centralized place.  This allows events to occur without needing to worry about specific dependencies on those events.  Take a look at the MVC pattern for some more insight.

Comment: I think i get it now. I've opted for the flag option because it is simplet, thanks anyway!

Comment: @Deigo If this is a simple program then definitely go with the flag.  MVC is really useful when you have a complex UI with many interacting elements.  Can you imagine having hundreds of flags, and flags for flags?  That what will eventually happen as your UI grows in complexity.  I'm all for KISS when it fits, so by all means, use the flag approach if that solves you problem.  Thanks!